# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 × 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/29670).

Comment: Link to last year's version: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018

Comment: Once the upvotes reaches 6, does the final score affect anything, like the frequency of the add?

Answer (score 62):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: [Repost from last year](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27812/5676)

Answer (score 40):

[image: Overleaf: Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with real-time PDF preview]

Answer (score 39):

[image: ProofWiki, the online compendium of mathematical proofs]

Comment: [Repost of last year](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27808/43351)

Comment: Nice project! Would be awesome if we could vote, so that the best proof floats on top. Oh wait, this is reinventing math.SE...

Comment: Simply beautiful.

Answer (score 35):

[image: Sage Mathematical Software Environment]

Comment: Reposting [last year's version](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27809/).

Answer (score 31):

[image: Create, animate, and share beautiful math in your browser]

Comment: I believe anyone who hasn't checked this out already definitely should. For years I've been looking for a 3D analgue to Desmos, and now I have found it. This calculator graphs beautifully and has a clear and intuitive interface,

Comment: BTW: I should add that I am the primary creator/maintainer of math3d.org, though definitely believe this site is of interest to the MSE community.

Comment: Although this site is still under construction, what's there works well and I've found it very useful.

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki thank you for that amazing site

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki very nice, what libraries does this use ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon You can see all the packages math3d uses on the github repo (https://github.com/ChristopherChudzicki/math3d-react). The math-oriented ones are MathBox (for 3d graphics), MathQuill (wysiwyg LaTeX editing), and MathJS (expression parsing + lots of other stuff). MathJS is actively maintained, the other two not so much (sadly).

Answer (score 30):

[image: Approach0.xyz]

Comment: [Repost](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018) from last year.

Answer (score 26):

[image: GAP - Group, Algorithms and Programming]

Comment: Repost from [last year](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27816#27816)

Answer (score 14):

[image: Collaborative Calculation in the Cloud]

Comment: This image size is 347 px x 287 px.

Comment: I have edited the image to make it 600 x 500 pixels.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Open-access web platform for open problems in mathematics]

Comment: I think this is a great idea for a site, by the way.  I've always wanted a directory of open problems with updates to proposed solutions.

Comment: @rschwieb, thanks for your comment! We launched this platform online at the end of last July and continue its development to this day. If you'll ever have a comment on the workings of the platform itself, or anything related to the concept in general, please let us know. This is a community project and the feedback we receive from the community is of utmost importance to us.

Comment: Can we search by research field? Example: "number theory"

Comment: @Basj, absolutely. There is an icon (looks like a magnifier, dark colored) near the search bar on top, pushing that will open a new window where one can choose a subject and search with it. The subjects are the same as those in arXiv.org, and Number theory is there of course, although most of the contributions we have right now are from Analysis of PDEs and Differential Geometry. Hopefully, other fields will become active in the future.

Comment: @Basj, one may also use the "Problem mining" tool, which is an automated pipeline that creates a periodically updated list of research papers (based on arXiv.org public data) which might contain a discussion on an open problem or a conjecture. There is a lot more data in that list, however, problem statements are not expanded manually, and only small snippets are extracted automatically from the articles' full texts, aiming at providing a quick indication whether the paper contains an open problem or not.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Operations Research Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 5):

[image: Graph theory and network analysis package for Mathematica]

Comment: this should make more sense on the mathematica SE

Answer (score 3):

[image: GitLab Pages Hugo official sample site]

Comment: related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6534/290189

Comment: I think personal blogs with decent math/graphics/text/comments functionality has yet to appear, and that discussion you linked deserves more attention for its own merit. Perhaps too soon to consider advertiszing for now.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Unluckily, unlike main site, there's no way to draw attention to a meta post by bounty.  IMHO, static blogs with static comments does a much more decent job than WordPress, the current solution adopted by many mathematicians, due to an array of reasons detailed in the linked answer.  The most significant ones are the hosting cost, SEO, and resistance and stability.

Answer (score 1):

[image: The Universe of Discourse]