# How can I update community ad for Operations Research site?

Tags: support

We have a community ad promoting a [proposed SE site for Operations Research](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research). The name of the proposed site recently changed, so I would like to change the image in the ad, and the URL it points to. Can I just edit [my answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30100/663638) in the community ads thread, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: What have you tried? (I mean, literally, did you try editing the answer? Did you observe any changes?)

Comment: I was reluctant to try editing the answer because I didn't want to break anything or cause hassles for the mods.

Comment: Well, in any case, you can see on that page that people have edited their answers before. If you're *really* reluctant, you can always delete your answer and post a new one. But editing should be fine.

Comment: Done. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Wow. You can type with your fingers crossed? That is ***very*** impressive! :-)