# Collaboration on Proofs

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm a burgeoning computer scientist and interested in collaborating with others on proofs and solutions to difficult problems, both for fun and for publication purposes. I'm wondering whether there is a feature on the SE that facilitates this? In other words, is there a space where people can communicate, share progress on an ongoing problem, and/or save content to a shared document? If not, why not? Can we expect something like this to come in the future? Thanks for reviewing my question.

Comment: I did this with another user last year (and it is still ongoing) via [chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). It is great for some casual collaboration, but note that all messages are publicly available. To write the end product up we used [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com) which, sadly, isn't part of SE, though it is frequently advertised here as part of [community ads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29676/471884).

Comment: which open problem ? Collatz can be modeled algebraically, Goldbach geometrically, Twin prime could arguably be proven inductively if we could find an easier way to induce. Grimm's could be supported via the prime number theorem etc.

Comment: Beyond conversations in Chat, it's possible that the project-based features of [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) might be useful for a really organized effort.  Of course there are other ways for documents to be shared on the Web, so project members might well start from a Chat environment and add functionality from outside Stack Exchange itself as needed.